# Apache Nutch 2.3 ant runtime build failed [cannot find symbol]

Tags: java, nutch

I am trying to work with apache nutch to crawl some of the website. While following a tutorial on youtube. I came up with so many errors and have successfully dealt with them, but the error I am encountering now, is really difficult for me to understand. Please help.
The tutorial I am following is at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AvyBiGuBc64&t=1482s

After successfully running Hbase, the next step to ant the nutch folder by using the following command

```
sudo ant runtime
```

whenever I run this command I get the error

```
Build Failed
/nutch/apache-nutch-2.3/build.xml:101: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

The details are as follows, Note: I am ignoring the warnings and just mentioning the errors.

```
[javac]
/nutch/apache-nutch-2.3/src/java/org/apache/nutch/webui/service/impl/CrawlServiceImpl.java:22:
error: cannot find symbol
[javac] import javax.annotation.Resource;
[javac]                        ^
[javac] symbol: class Resource
[javac] location: package javax.annotation

[javac]
/nutch/apache-nutch-2.3/src/java/org/apache/nutch/webui/service/impl/CrawlServiceImpl.java:46:
error: cannot find symbol
[javac] @Resource
[javac] ^
[javac] symbol: class Resource
[javac] location: package javax.annotation

[javac]
/nutch/apache-nutch-2.3/src/java/org/apache/nutch/webui/service/impl/CrawlServiceImpl.java:49:
error: cannot find symbol
[javac] @Resource
[javac] ^
[javac] symbol: class Resource
[javac] location: package javax.annotation


[javac]
/nutch/apache-nutch-2.3/src/java/org/apache/nutch/webui/service/impl/CrawlServiceImpl.java:52:
error: cannot find symbol
[javac] @Resource
[javac] ^
[javac] symbol: class Resource
[javac] location: package javax.annotation

[javac]
/nutch/apache-nutch-2.3/src/java/org/apache/nutch/webui/service/impl/NutchInstanceServiceImpl.java:34:
error: cannot find symbol
[javac] @Resource
[javac] ^
[javac] symbol: class Resource
[javac] location: package javax.annotation
```

Similar errors in both the files in different lines.

**How can I solve this issue? Note:I am using debain9 on virtual box.**

Comment: what is the java version that you use? It seems that either the JDK or you're missing some libs. Run `sudo ant compile` (btw ... not sure why you use `sudo`) to see if this is the `target` where the error happens so that we identify if the problem is in `compile` target. Also, list the link to the Youtube video tutorial you were following ...

Comment: @azbarcea I already did in the question. You can see the link of youtube.. The weird thing is I have installed jdk-8 and even put the JAVA_HOME variable in the files hbase-env.sh, in .profile also in /etc/environment file like this.
JAVA_HOME="/home/farrukh/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_221"
but whenever I check it with "which java" command it tells me that I have jdk-11.0.4 also java -version tells me that I have openjdk version "11.0.4"

Answer (score 0):

javax.annotation is no longer part of java. I had to compile with version 8 of java. I no longer have these error messages.